# How to solve Yii grid error when have broken join?

Tags: php, yii

Now if I have two tables users and orders and they have relation so every order have user_id but now if I have for any reason some user_id=0 or empty for some orders , if I tried to using yii cgridview it cause problem when try to sort or search because the other row which have user id=0 not found , can any one advice me how to solve this, I tried to change the jointype but it only working on inner join and off course not displaying all rows because it's inner.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is modify your search function of your model to exclude all the ones without a valid user_id.

Something like

```
public function search(...)
{
     if ($this->user) // Points to your relation
     {
          // Search stuff here
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
array(            
              'name'=>'user_id', 
              'value'=>'(empty($data->user->user_id)) ? "" : $data->user->user_id',

            ),   // user being your relation, that code goes inside the CgridView
```